# Levelling off a surface for veneer

Tags: veneer, filler

I've been making a pretty basic case from plywood and would like to apply some veneer.  Unfortunately, one surface needs levelling out because the plywood was a tiny bit warped.  I don't have pictures to hand but can upload some if needed.

My plan is to apply wood filler then sand it down... but maybe there's a better way?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The warp is not huge (a couple of mm at the worst point) but it's present on the top surface, which butts up against the side.  So, at the point where the warp is at it's worst, the side piece sits slightly proud.  I could sand down the side piece.  Sounds like that would be a more robust option, but perhaps less aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: How large is the piece of plywood? How much is it out of level? and how large is the area depression area?

Comment: This might work... o-k-a-y.... but the type of filler you use (wood fillers come in many flavours), the veneer type and thickness, plus the glue you're planning to use, are all factors. This is both for now and for the long term. I wouldn't expect this to last in good condition for a long time, in case this is a factor.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments!  It's about a 2 mm out of level.  I realise that I've not described the issue quite right so I'm going to make an edit now.

Comment: The depression area is probably about 200mm x 150mm and the piece of ply is 550mm x 220mm.

Comment: 2mm, ouch. That's actually a bad warp. If you have any hand planes and know how to use them I'd be tempted to suggest planing down to level, since you have plenty of thickness available. Planing and plywood tend not to be associated but you can plane it successfully if you don't mind how it looks, and since you're intending to cover it this is a situation where it might be appropriate as you'll be completely hiding it. If you do go ahead with filler it'll still be fairly challenging to end up with a totally level surface, and wood fillers really aren't intended for wide-area coverage.

Comment: Thanks, Graphus.  I don't have a plane, but it sounds like I might need to get one.  I appreciate your guidance on this.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone!  There's a bunch of really useful tips in the two answers and all the comments.  I feel that I have enough information to be getting on with now.  I'm tempted to write my own answer to the question, bringing together various bits and pieces from other people's contributions... is that acceptable?

Comment: It's generally considered good form to up vote all answers that you found helpful, and to give a check-mark to the one you found _most_ helpful. Self-answers are always acceptable, however, when they simply summarize what was in other answers, maybe not so much - if you're adding new or different info, then absolutely.

Comment: *"The construction of many glued up boards should minimize any seasonal wood movement."* You're a woodworker, of course you need a plane :-) Seriously though, even power-tool users often own one or two (generally a block plane if just one) but if you're not a dedicated power-tool guy then planes aren't even optional, they're a must-have. If you need guidance on purchasing gimme a shout, I'll be able to help if you're buying new or secondhand.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, FreeMan.  Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation required to upvote answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your thoughts and suggestions.  In the end, partly because of the tools I had at my disposal, I just gambled on using a filler – in this case, [Big Boy Body Filler](https://www.toolstation.com/big-boy-filler-ultra-fine/p40826?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=googleshoppingfeed&gclid=CjwKCAjwoc_8BRAcEiwAzJevtS-zls2QLF9erDXonlhG5a4cvarjmaKqAXX9qqDwXZ6-irhx2cOf9BoCBDsQAvD_BwE).

Aside from the fact that the filler smells bad and creates horrible fine dust when being sanded, it went quite well.

My veneering skills are now the limiting factor.

[image: side one][image: side two]

Comment: I know, it's a bit ropey, but this thing is my first attempt at woodwork in about 25 years :)

Comment: I think that with a little more patience and practice I'd have been able to get a good smooth and level surface so I'm going with this as the accepted answer.  EDIT: it is actually quite level but I'm conscious that it looks a bit ugly in these photos so perhaps it's not up to the standards of others.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever done simple small veneers, but my research suggests that surface prep in terms of flatness is less important than cleanliness. All surfaces must be

- Acclimatized
- Dust free; really, really dust free
- Free of oils, including finger grease

Your results will only be as good as your prep. Just make sure the surface is reasonably true.

(As an aside, note that plywood *is* a type of veneer, so you are actually adhering two veneers together, if that helps with your research.)

If you have to use filler, you will have to do research to figure out if it needs additional glue preparation. This goes for any surface, really. But with plywood in the home shop, the assumption is that you will be using contact cement and a roller. That is, I am assuming you do not have a hydraulic or vacuum press.

So, your prep work will be more about preparing the surfaces for gluing up with a high-solids contact cement. This may include not just sanding to true (but not necessarily smooth -- check to see if your glue wants surfaces rough for good adherence) but also meticulous dry and damp dust removal, and probably at least one wipe with denatured alcohol.

You can also get adhesive backed veneers if you just want that convenience.

Comment: This is a good Answer, but I'm not sure it'll address the OP's needs given he's dealing with a warp. This suggest to me that the filler work will have to be extensive, and if so that's likely to be the main obstacle to a successful outcome. We'll see, assuming we get an update with the details requested/suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, jdv!  I really appreciate them and will re-read this once I'm ready to apply the veneer.

Comment: Depending on the warp, the veneer might just follow the curve, but we can't know for sure.

Comment: I suspect that the veneer would follow the curve of the warp, were it not for the fact that the other part of the butt joint protrudes slightly.  I.e. There would likely be a small gap under the veneer.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to be a lot of filler and it would have to be a filler that bonds with your veneering glue well, also sanding it perfectly level is going to be a challenge. It's hard to advise without seeing the piece, but I would try figuring how to replace a warped part, or if that's impossible then whether a construction could be modified so that warped plywood part is level, i.e. maybe adding a support or a stiffener, gluing a corner block, gluing it to the butting piece, etc.

There's a chance that a veneer might straighten the warped part if the part is thin. On thin panels it is recommended to glue a backer veneer to prevent warping, so maybe this could be used to your advantage - gluing a thicker backer or not gluing a backer at all, depending which way you want it to counter warp. This approach gives no guarantees of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, eGlyph!  Much appreciated.  It's going to be hard to replace the warped part, unfortunately, and it's quite thick at 18mm.  I'll try to get a decent picture of it tomorrow and upload that.

Answer (score 0):

> My plan is to apply wood filler then sand it down... but maybe there's a better way?

Typical "plastic wood" type filler is good for filling nails holes and small dings, but not always great for filling large, flat areas the way, say, auto body filler is. To fill a broad, 2mm deep depression, you'd probably be better off with something that's very strong and stable with good adhesive qualities, like epoxy thickened with wood flour or other fibers, or auto body filler.

> So, at the point where the warp is at it's worst, the side piece sits slightly proud. I could sand down the side piece. Sounds like that would be a more robust option, but perhaps less aesthetically pleasing.

If it's not too late, I think you'd be better off removing the top of the case and replacing it with plywood that's flat. It'll never be as easy to fix your project as it is now, before you add the veneer. As jdv explained, the key to a good veneer job is a good substrate

Comment: Thank you Caleb!  It would have been pretty hard to remove the warped piece, largely due to my poor decision making during construction :)